# How to prioritize the reponse over request in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I have a code that looks something like this:

```
class SomeController {

  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  public Task<dynamic> SomeAction() {
    Task.Run<dynamic>(() => {
      var response = client.GetAsync(new Uri(someUrl));
      return response.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>().Result;
    });
  }
}
```

Now, I call this api with many requests (around 300) and the 'someUrl' returns the response after about 200ms.

After adding some console logs I can see a behavior:

- All the 200 requests arrive and request the someUrl resource
- The first 2-3 requests to someUrl are handled and returned properly
- Other responses are waiting for all the 300 requests to arrive and only then they are returned back...

I have heard that there is no prioritization of responses over incoming requests in situations like these but it seems weird to me. It seems like the requests coming to my server and the responses that are coming from the someUrl are on the same queue and until all the requests are sent no response can be handled.

Anyone else encountered this situation? Anyone knows how to handle it properly?

Thanks!